# keydown events ( press say 1 it opens a process press 2 it closes that process)

Tags: c#, winforms

i am creating a application that when you press 1 it will open say SQL and if you press 2 it will close SQL

ok so this is the problem if i have multiple buttons with which i use the keydown event on it only works on the first button ,
completely ignoring my other keydowns needless to say this is a problem because my application consists of about 10 buttons all with their own keydowns and specific keys , does someone have a idea how i can get this to work properly

**declaring my process**

```
    private static Process GetSQL()
    {
        Process sql = new Process();
        return sql;
    }
```

**how i kill my process**

```
        public static void killSql()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process[] procs = null;

            try
            {
                procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("Ssms");

                Process sqlProc = procs[0];

                if (!sqlProc.HasExited)
                {
                    sqlProc.Kill();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (procs != null)
                {
                    foreach (Process s in procs)
                    {
                        s.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private void btnSQL_KeyDown1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F3)
            {
                killSql();
            }


        }
```

**how i call it**

```
    private void btnSQL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Process SQL = GetSQL();
            SQL.StartInfo.FileName = (@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL                  Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe");
            SQL.Start();

        }

        private void btnSQL_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F5)
            {
                this.KeyPreview = true;
                GetSQL();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do these buttons listen for different keys (for example button1 listens for F1 and button2 two for F2), or do they listen for the same keys (for example button1 and button2 both listen for F1)?

Comment: 1 button listens for both f5 say to open and f3 to close belong to 1 button , i thought it would be a fun little gadget to have on my desktop :)

Comment: So, more than one button user the sames Keys? If yes how do you separate to which button it does belong? If not, then why don't you use the keydown event of the form ???

Answer (score 1):

Please lookup this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In short terms - only one control can have focus at any given time and this focus will recieve the keyboard input. I would suggest you make your window listen for keyboard input.

You can do something like
declare a method, which will launch your process:

```
void StartSQL()
{
         Process SQL = GetSQL();
         SQL.StartInfo.FileName = (@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL                  Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe");
         SQL.Start();
}
```

and then just call this method when you have a keydown event:

```
void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.F5)
    {
        StartSQL();
    }
    else if(....)
    .....
}
```

and have your corresponding button only be used for clicking (what it is supposed to be used for):

```
private void btnSQL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         StartSQL();
    }
```

Comment: i kinda got that bit but i wish to know if there is some evil forbidden code that will allow me to get this done i am sure lots of people are irritated by this and someone should have figured something out and a example would be greatly appreciated if possible

Comment: @Wolf Your app structure is just not good. Buttons should only be used to be clicked, not to listen for keyboard events. Look at the updated answer

Comment: i understand about the structure but i needed the app to work like i explained above(QUICK ACCESS to all my programs) and luckily for the time being it is just for fun ,i am not coding for keeps just yet with this app. Thanks a lot for the update i will see how it works if i become desperate il figure something out